# How to change current job?

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I have a full time job - not bad. But I am getting bored and I am almost getting convinced everyday that it is time to quit. I am a very passionate programmer. At the job that I am working on, it is just routine mundane work. The technologies used are old school. It requires knowledge of a domain ( I don't want to specify because its not that relevant to this question ) that is not at all related to what I studied. I just can't make myself interested in that domain. 
Now, I am actually trying hard to pick up whatever is needed to get into a new company that has better and interesting problems to solve.

But having a full time job and a family with a demanding kid :) ( love her so much though ) I m just not able to find time to advance my skills and attend some interviews confidently.

Do you experts have any advice especially from those who had been in the same boat before?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- this is difficult to answer because the question is pretty broad. Can you narrow it down to a specific question that could be answered objectively?

Comment: You just have to put in the work to get what you want. If you want a new job, set aside time and study for the interviews. Even though you have a lot of responsibilities to your family and current job, there isn't a magical job granting fairy you can plead your case to unfortunately. You have manage all three things for a while and it will suck, but it'll be temporary.

Answer (score 3):

> But having a full time job and a family with a demanding kid :) ( love
>   her so much though ) I m just not able to find time to advance my
>   skills and attend some interviews confidently.
>
> Do you experts have any advice especially from those who had been in
>   the same boat before?

There are no silver bullets. You just have to do the work.

Some do their knowledge building at night after the kids are put to bed, early mornings before others get up, or on weekends. (While working full time, being married with two children, I still attended school nights and weekends, yet managed keep on top of changing technologies and changed jobs several times. It can be done.)

Everyone I know has had a full time job and a family, yet they all manage to find time to keep abreast of new technologies and attend interviews confidently.

You have to decide your priorities. If you want a new job badly enough, you'll find a way to make the time.

That fact that you don't seem to be able to do so may mean that you don't really want to put in the effort at this time and are content enough in your existing job.

Comment: To the user who attempted to edit, the OP of the question specifically asked _any advice especially from those who had been in the same boat before_ and you tried to remove anecdotal information? If you don't like this answer, you can downvote or even flag it. But, please **do not waste other's time to reject your edit**.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere. `Some do their knowledge building at night after the kids are put to bed, early mornings before others get up, or on weekends.` This is where I am struggling at. But thanks for the answer , it certainly helps me realize there are more people who does this than I think.